# File moving/compressing/deleting automation in a script runnable within cmd

Tags: windows, loops, for-loop

I have a problem.

I need to create a back up from a folder - lets name it `A` - and I am manually moving it to folder `B` because `A` gets saturated of documents every 3 days approximately.

I want to create an infinite loop that executes every 2 days and does the following:

1. move the files from `A` to `B` and delete the files that were moved from `A`, with the condition that I can only move the files that have been there more than 2 days.
2. In `B` I want to use the type `*.txt` > `textfilesbackup.txt` so I can compress all documents into 1. Once the command has been executed, erase those files that were compressed, (this command also has to be executed every 3 days)
   if someone could help me, that would be great.
   Thanks.

Comment: what you call an infinite loop is more like a recurrent task. You can check https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: if i wanted to create the recurrent task how would i put it in command propmt?

Comment: @ParkSungjae The feature you're looking for on Windows is "Scheduled Tasks". Google `schtasks.exe` if you want to use a command line interface